# Symfony2 & PHP Traits with entities relation embedded

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, traits, relation

In Symfony2, I just try recently to think in terms of traits, to create some sort of behaviors.
Let's say I have an address attribute in an entity. I externalized attributes, getters and setters related to this in an AddressableTrait.

But what if address become an entity? I started to try to define my OneToMany relation in my trait, as if it was in a regular entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class AddressableTrait {

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="XXXX\GlobalBundle\Entity\Address", inversedBy="What to put here" )
 */
protected $addresses;

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}

/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $addresses
 */
public function setAddresses($addresses)
{
    $this->addresses = $addresses;
}
}
```

What to put in the inversedBy? The purpose of the trait if precisely to embed all the behavior feature, so I think that at least using traditionnal annotation/YML/XML,it's not possible to achieve.

I digged a bit into it and found [this very interesting link](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/) that seems to allow you to defines relation via events, but there is still logic to add to "finish" relations.

**UPDATE :** 
Using the above link, I managed to created dynamic ManyToMany relation. the schema update works when creating, but if I comment the dynamic relation, a schema:update --dump-sql doesn't remove it. It seems to work add-only. Any clue to force the dynamic mapping to stick to the real relations addition/removal?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem using traits in entities. For regular database values (scalar, DateTime) traits worked fine, but when I tried to define entity relations in traits the doctrine migrations bundle would convert the property to a varchar field.

The only way I could find to fix creating proper entity relation properties was by moving them out of the trait and into the entity class itself.

Comment: If you go there [link](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/), you find a way to keep them in traits. Furthermore, in some ManyToOne  relations, you don't need to define both side. Those relations are particularily useful in the traits case, because you only define the relation many side :
`trait Monositeable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\MultisiteBundle\Entity\Site")
     */
    protected $site;

}`